# Laravel Websockets: Invalid status line

Tags: laravel, apache, websocket

I'm trying to connect to my websockets server from outside the local network. I deployed a web app based on Laravel, everything works fine when developing locally, but deploying the app to my Raspberry Pi won't let my websockets server work. The problem might be with my Apache config, but I'm not sure. I'm using a **Let's Encrypt** certificate, so everything is configured as it should in Laravel and in Apache.

The browser can reach the websockets server, but at websocket's console messages it says this: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line`.

It looks like the Websocket server is not returning a 101 code, but I don't know how to debug or fix this. I'm using the 443 port for websockets, so this is my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName drink.myhost.org
    ServerAlias www.drink.myhost.org

    # WEBSOCKETS CONFIG
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass "/app/ABCFEDG" "ws://127.0.0.1:6001"
    ProxyPass "/app/ABCFEDG" "wss://127.0.0.1:6001"

    ProxyPassReverse "/app/ABCFEDG" "ws://127.0.0.1:6001/app/ABCFEDG"
    ProxyPassReverse "/app/ABCFEDG" "wss://127.0.0.1:6001/app/ABCFEDG"


    ServerAdmin webmaster@drink.myhost.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drink/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/drink.myhost.org/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/drink.myhost.org/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```